# How to build stacked bar chart overlapping with d3js

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, stacked-chart

I'm planning to use d3js for building a stacked bar chart which showing number of email was sent, opened and clicked, With normal stacked bar, there will be 3 blocks for each column, and `stack` on each other.

For example: Total email sent was 100, opened was 80 and clicked was 30, then there are 3 blocks with value of each one is 100, 80 and 30. But it's not showing exactly the statistic, so I would like to build an overlapping stacked bar like
[image]

Here is an example, but I didn't find any d3 chart or something else supports it, I guess we need to customize them.

Comment: Does it mean you want the `rect`s sorted by value, maybe the next day `Sent` has the lowest count? Or do you want the grouped bar chart https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: @rioV8, Actually, `Sent` always is highest value, and then to `Opened` and lowest value is `Clicked` as normal logic. It's exactly group bar, but we are grouping them into stacked bar, because of time range is quite long, so we want to save space

Comment: Then just "merge" the normal bar chart with the grouped bar chart ans only use one x scale. Render like grouped but use x0 instead of x1.

Answer (score 0):

I have created stack bar chart with brush and I think it is helpful to you, you need to pass data and also you need to specify x_label_KEY which is you want show on x axis.

I have passed different dataset but you can pass your data to check. For example you can download from here - 
https://github.com/Umesh-Markande/D3-Graph-With-Brush/blob/master/stackBarWithBrush.html